# Android trouble with POST data to a remote database

Tags: android, database, post

I'm trying to send data from an Android application to a remote database using a PHP file. The problem I'm ecountering is the app doesn't crash and no data are sent: i know that I can see the result with a JSON response from the PHP file, but I don't use it because I don't know how to handle JSON.

Here you are the php code and the activity related:

```
<?php

        $Nome;
        $Tavolo;

        //Apro la connessione con il server mySQL

        $Conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if(!$Conn)
        {
            die('Errore di connessione: ' .mysql_error());


        }


            //Seleziono il mio database
            $DBS = mysql_select_db('ordinazioni', $Conn);
            if(!$DBS)
            {
                die('Accesso al database non riuscito: ' .mysql_error());
            }

            //echo "Mi sono connesso!";

            $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
            $Tavolo = $_POST['Tavolo'];

            $strSQL = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Comande (Nome, Tavolo) VALUES ('$Nome', '$Tavolo')");


?>
```

Android code;

```
public class AggiungiProdotto extends Activity 

{

TextView tv1;
    private static String indirizzo ="http://10.0.2.2/tesina/Aggiungi_Ordinazione";
    private String Nome = "test";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aggiungi_prodotto);

    Invio();


}

public void Invio() 
{
    int NumTavolo = 2;
    final String Tavolo = Integer.toString(NumTavolo);

    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {




            //Intent intent = getIntent();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(indirizzo);


            try 
            {

                List<NameValuePair> Comanda = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                Comanda.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Nome", Nome));
                Comanda.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tavolo", Tavolo));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Comanda));

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                final String Risposta = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                tv1.setText("Response : " + Risposta);

            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    };

    thread.start();
}

}
```

Could you help me to resolve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your data with your request.

Do

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Comanda));
```

before

```
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Store the response in an HttpResponse object and post the status code and message from the server

Comment: I am new to this part of Android, so could you tell me please? I think i have to declare "HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)" then I add a breakpoint to see it with Eclipse debugging right?

Comment: Eclipse says response is not used. By the way the debugger doesnt show any Httpresponse variable, should i have to add HttpEntity maybe?

Comment: Instead of debugger, just print the response code and message

Comment: I don't have nothing. I also changed the structure of the activity (edited code) but nothing appears.